# Playing audio with useEffect hook on page load

Tags: reactjs, audio, react-hooks

I am building a tribute page and I want to have my audio play when the page loads, every time.
So far it seems to play only sometimes and I'm not sure why.

```
var audio = new Audio("theme.mp3");
  const Playit = () => {
audio.play();
  }
  useEffect(() => Playit(), [Playit]);
```

I am sure that I am using the `useEffect` hook improperly because I am trying to make it work like `componentDidMount`

How would I get the audio to play whenever the page loads?

 Thank you in advance.

Comment: try without any deps in useEffect and an empty deps array.

Comment: ```useEffect(() => Playit(), []);``` No change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out you can't have an autoplaying audio on chrome. Chrome blocks it. You can however have audio controls like so

```
const [audio, SetAudio] = useState("");

  const Playit = () => {
    audio.play();
  };
  const Stopit = () => {
    
    audio.pause();
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    SetAudio(new Audio("theme.mp3"));
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var audio = new Audio("theme.mp3");
  const Playit = () => {
audio.play();
  }
  useEffect(() => Playit(), []);
```

Comment: This is just my code? Did you forget to make your changes?

Comment: Do not use any dependencies..It causes it to run again for each change in the Playit

Comment: `useEffect(() => Playit(), []);`

Comment: It is still not playing. Here is the github repo if you want to take another look https://github.com/Imstupidpleasehelp/bladerunnertribute/blob/main/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

Create the audio object inside `Playit` function. Also pass an empty array as the second argument in the `useEffect` hook.

```
const Playit = () => {
    var audio = new Audio("theme.mp3");
    audio.play();
}
useEffect(() => {Playit()}, []);
```

Comment: After applying the changes the issue persists

Answer (score 0):

sorry i cant add a comment.

It seems that when running the `Playit()`, theme.mp3 is not ready for play.Does it not play every time when the page is refreshed

Comment: It does not play when the page is refreshed, I've only heard it play a few times and I don't know how I did it. (I didn't change any code)